# ASP.NET Core MVC : view model IList to ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

My current view model:

```
public class CustomerVM
{
     public string fname;
     public virtual IList<DocumentVM>? Documents { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class DocumentVM
{
     public string UniqueNo;
     ...some code ommitted
}
```

Below are Chtml design. one customer can fill 2 d documents.

```
...some code ommited
 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label asp-for="customer.FirstName" class="col-form-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="customer.FirstName" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="customer.FirstName" type="text" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
 
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="customer.Documents[0].DocTypeId" class="col-form-label">Document Type</label>
        <select asp-for="customer.Documents[0].DocTypeId" asp-items="@Model.customer.DocumentTypeList" class="form-control">
            <option>Choose</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label asp-for="customer.Documents[0].UniqueNo" class="col-form-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="customer.Documents[0].UniqueNo" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="customer.Documents[0].UniqueNo" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="customer.Documents[1].DocTypeId" class="col-form-label">Document Type</label>
        <select asp-for="customer.Documents[1].DocTypeId" asp-items="@Model.customer.DocumentTypeList" class="form-control">
            <option>Choose</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label asp-for="customer.Documents[1].UniqueNo" class="col-form-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="customer.Documents[1].UniqueNo" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="customer.Documents[1].UniqueNo" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

This code works perfectly. But I need to change my view model Customer

```
 public virtual IList<DocumentVM>? Documents { get; set; } = null!;
```

to

```
 public virtual ICollection<DocumentVM>? Documents { get; set; } = null!;
```

I can't directly access index from Razor view. Is it possible to change my view design change `IList` to `ICollection` object in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by incorporate collection?

Comment: How did you reference this Documents collection on Razor view. You can use IEnumerable in place of ICollection and same will be used on Razor view.

Comment: sory updated in the question..i need to add 2 documents  to icollection object and submit the form..am accessing Documents[1] and document [2] index hard coded..is it possible to do dynamically

Comment: This is actually Customer view with 2 documents  ( which is Documents list) submit the form  finally..

Answer (score 1):

You want to save multiple documents on form submit, so on form rendering use for loop which will populate the strongly typed controls according to collection and can be submit accordingly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].UniqueNo)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].UniqueNo)....
 }
```

Comment: Initially when view customer.Documents is null.how will do count?

Comment: Your requirement to add 2 documents, instead of `i<Model.Count` you can use i<2

Comment: what do you mean tag helper @Ajt ? Did my answer worked for you? If so then kindly accept & upvote.